# echo BLOBs from database (utf-8)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, blob

I'm currently working on a web-app with a utf-8 MYSQL database. There are some images saved as BLOBs which I need to display. 
In all my naivety i thought it would just be something like that:

```
if($image = $result->fetch_object())
{
    header('Content-Type: {$image->mimetype}');
    echo $image->data;
}
```

Which doesn't work. To me it seemed like the image-data is converted to utf-8. So I thought I simply do a dirty hack like

```
echo utf8_decode($image->data);
```

... again without any luck. 
After that I removed the header(...) call to compare the binary result against

```
echo file_get_contents('sameImageAsInDatabase.jpg');
```

And there are some tiny differences

file_get_contents(...) - works:

> ÿØÿàJFIFddÿìDuckyPÿá ¨http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ Â© 2010 Boston University all rights reserved ÿîAdobedÀÿÛ„     ÿÀÌÙÿÄì  !1AQ"aq‘¡2#±ÁÑBRbr‚’3$ðáñ¢²CS%Òcƒ4Âs“£³DT& dt„5ÃÓ”EU6¤´ÔuV'âòÄ…W!1AQaq"ð‘¡±ÁÑ2BRáb#3ñr‚’¢²ÂCS$Òc4sƒ“³%â£Td5òDÿÚ?©Ÿ”²XãÆ6z:¿üWöyíÄTš/_þ+ÿXà¨P0Ž&Y?¬q·+ûõEXªÌ?ß?»Qý¸*ƒ­Ãªÿ8*À3ï¯Y«ï?·X¬¿ñŸÝ¨œF¡t†GÌ¦‘I,àµ?£<ÉÒ.=·¿_¦ˆ`º@s-¤Óé`p®d¨vÝ—¿ôÒ6• E%äú`wÒ9ÇØ×Ç;ÑTsé‡oÒFÅciBÕìxÇÛÝ®ÒÇâ0Òƒ‡fX/Û¾¼jsÖêÁâ2t Åí¨q–íÇ¶b?@r (ø_fî§jxÌÿ·¶F¿Ã;8ÿÝ¤Ï‘šOúX5°¢þÙÇþèßdÿ¥ƒS ³Û{9Ïå3ñêIÿKªAD%›µöf÷fZŽRÉÿK¹"päso«l;{¸6¶Áå¶‚òÅçsÔfÔâM#í@bau·FD ¨V {zÙüÔ‡úGöâýLJ ¦¼¼5­Ä‚¿Ê?·R(nîùÜH¤n ‘Dnnûù¬ß·P¡±suÿÄI_çŸÛ‰« 7Tÿ¼K_çœF Òl\ÜÇ“ÙæoÛ‚¡@3>_Þ$÷ëoÛˆ¨´Aÿ31ûÌ™sÖpUFnn?ø™s<5ŸÛ‚ ƒ>fæŸ÷‰<‹Û‚¬šóñëÉŸòÏíÁˆQëÏÿÄIîÔpU…¦¸¹§–âN5 1ý¸*ÈhRë/ïývý¸š…u®™=žvý¸*ÂŒ!ÖW•ek™‹åF¥GÇB†æ|¹”ø‚çá‚¬ƒ ÄõÎâPyùš‡

database - doesn't work:

> ÿØÿàJFIFddÿìDuckyPÿá ¨http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ Â© 2010 Boston University all rights reserved ÿîAdobedÀÿÛ?     ÿÀÌÙÿÄì  !1AQ"aq?¡2#±ÁÑBRbr??3$ðáñ¢²CS%Òc?4Âs?£³DT& dt?5ÃÓ?EU6¤´ÔuV'âòÄ?W!1AQaq"ð?¡±ÁÑ2BRáb#3ñr??¢²ÂCS$Òc4s??³%â£Td5òDÿÚ?©??²XãÆ6z:¿üWöyíÄT?/_þ+ÿXà¨P0?&Y?¬q·+ûõEXªÌ?ß?»Qý¸*?­Ãªÿ8*À3ï¯Y«ï?·X¬¿ñ?Ý¨?F¡t?GÌ¦?I,àµ?£<ÉÒ.=·¿_¦?`º@s-¤Óé`p®d¨vÝ?¿ôÒ6? E%äú`wÒ9ÇØ×Ç;ÑTsé?oÒFÅciBÕìxÇÛÝ®ÒÇâ0Ò??fX/Û¾¼jsÖêÁâ2t Åí¨q?íÇ¶b?@r (ø_fî§jxÌÿ·¶F¿Ã;8ÿÝ¤Ï??OúX5°¢þÙÇþèßdÿ¥?S ³Û{9Ïå3ñêIÿKªAD%?µöf÷fZ?RÉÿK¹"päso«l;{¸6¶Áå¶?òÅçsÔfÔâM#í@bau·FD ¨V {zÙüÔ?úGöâýLJ ¦¼¼5­Ä?¿Ê?·R(nîùÜH¤n ?Dnnûù¬ß·P¡±suÿÄI_ç?Û?« 7Tÿ¼K_ç?F Òl\ÜÇ?ÙæoÛ?¡@3>_Þ$÷ëoÛ?¨´Aÿ31ûÌ?sÖpUFnn?ø?s<5?Û? ?>fæ?÷?ÍGXÔ`?Ü?Ì?Þíûq5aFk©qJüÔ?×?· Ò?î³¥Ä??5Û?©@MÍ×üiôíÁP us?3Ëìó?Û?¡@1qÿÄKìóÛ?¤?ù??ÿ¼IýsûpT(¯sÇæ$>vý¸?lÜ\

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: add the header charset = utf8

Comment: can you explain what is `{$image->mimetype}` ?

Comment: yes123: doesn't change anything

Comment: {$image->mimetype} is currently simply 'image/jpeg'

Answer (score 2):

Don't do utf encoding/decoding - you're dealing with BINARY data, not TEXT data. By chance you'll probably end up with some byte sequences in the binary data that LOOK like utf code points, and the encode/decode sequence will corrupt your file.

Comment: yes but somehow it seems that my binary data is converted to utf-8 somewhere in the query. i know that utf8_decode isn't a clean solution (actually it seems that it isn't a solution at all)

Comment: What's the field type in the database? BLOB or TEXT? Text fields are subject to charset conversion (based on connection and table collation settings). BLOB fields are not touched at all and are sent as-is.